# How can I store the data in the foreach loop in PHP? (Hangman Game)

Tags: php, foreach, return

I have a problem with the store the data in `foreach` loop.!

It's Hangman game and when the user inputs the character to check the answer,

```php
echo "Please enter a guess: ";
$userChar = stream_get_line(STDIN,1024,PHP_EOL);
//guessChar($hangman,$userChar); 
//Display a masked version of the name according to the attributes in the Array
$inputArray [] =$userChar;
foreach(str_split($hangman)as $char)
{

    if(in_array($char,$inputArray,true))
    {
    echo $char;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "*";
    }

}
```

But in there, I want to store the string what console shows to compare the hangman's answers to finish game or not

[image]

I want to get that blocked string to pass the function which is used for check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all the guesses saved up. Just output them.

`echo implode('', $inputArray);`

Comment: If I want to compare the value of the implode(' ',$inputArray) = $hangman , regardless of string order which function do I have to use?
I mean, $hangman(which save 'abcd') =$implode(which save 'dabc')

Comment: Is your intent to find whether the player has got all the puzzle guessed? `$hangman(which save 'abcd') =$implode(which save 'dabc')` isn't particularly close to PHP syntax, so it's hard to tell your intent.